# How can a program (.NET) tell if it is being run as a different user?

Tags: .net, runas

Is there a way to detect from my .NET program whether it is being run as the desktop user normally or being run as a different user using the "run as a different user" menu option/runas command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Getting the user which ran the program is easier, you can use `Environment.UserName` or `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`.
Links to the difference between them are located below...

Now, getting the ***logged in user*** is a little more tricky.
I use the following method (I think I found it here in SO a while back). What it does is check who is the owner of the `explorer.exe` process (which is the logged in user):

```
private string GetExplorerUser()
{
    var query = new ObjectQuery(
        "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = 'explorer.exe'");

    var explorerProcesses = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query).Get();

    foreach (ManagementObject mo in explorerProcesses)
    {
       String[] ownerInfo = new string[2];
       mo.InvokeMethod("GetOwner", (object[])ownerInfo);

       return String.Concat(ownerInfo[1], @"\", ownerInfo[0]);
    }

    return string.Empty;
}
```

The method above requires the `System.Managment` dll

**Update:** 
Method above works fine, based on OP's comments - added another option :

Getting first username from `Win32_ComputerSystem`:

```
 ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT UserName FROM Win32_ComputerSystem");
 ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();
 string username = (string)collection.Cast<ManagementBaseObject>().First()["UserName"];
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Unfortunately the reason I want to know this is to launch explorer when a different user with the /separate switch but normally when not!

Comment: Thanks, any suggestions though? I may be being stupid but I'm staring at task manager and can't see a suitable process.

Comment: Added another option for use to use.